# Django one custom model field to two db columns

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to create a custom field that receives a datetime string and store data in two db columns.
I am reading [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-model-fields/) but not getting how to do it with more than one db column.

It is a legacy db, so I can not change db tables layout.

I have this model right now.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    mixing_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    mixing_datetime_utc_offset_seconds = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to create a field that lets the front end (it is an API with DRF) just send a datetime string (instead of datetime and offset separately), and let the backend do the work behind the scenes.
So the idea would be:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    mixing_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    mixing_datetime_utc_offset_seconds = models.IntegerField()
    datetime = MyCustomDatetimeField() # This also should not be sent to db
```

So, to clarify, the idea is let the front end do this request:

```
frontend_client.post('server_url', payload={'datetime': '2021-07-02T14:34:49+00:00'}
```

And then de backend will so some calciulations and set both mixing_datetime and mixing_datetime_utc_offset_seconds

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What exactly does the backend do behind the scenes? Are you looking to process this datetime string from the front end, and save it in `mixing_datetime` and `mixing_datetime_utc_offset_seconds`?

Comment: @bdbd I add more context. The front end just send a string. The processing will be done in the backend

Comment: Ok now I understand your situation. I deleted my answer as it does not answer your question. But yes django's custom model fields are for custom fields that will eventually be reflected in the database, so if you want to do it this way you will probably have to do a lot of overriding.

Comment: You can probably just write a method (in the model class or as a mixin) that accepts the datetime string, and processes it for those two model fields. It should be fairly simple to handle in the serializers/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I came with this solution. It is not what I asked (A custom field of django models), but as it is an API what I am doing, I decided to make a DRF serializer custom field.
If you are not working with DRF, probably you can overwrite model's save method.

This is the DRF serializer custom field.

```
class CustomDateTimeField(serializers.Field):
    """Custom field used to convert a string in isoformat into other two fields.
    So the caller instead of sending datetime and offset, will only send the string, and internally we 
    are going to split it in the two respective fields.
    Same when caller requests data, it will receive only one datetime field. (output pf to_representation).

    In a model we are going to have two fields that will follow this naming pattern:
        >> datetime = models.DateTimeField()
        >> offset_seconds = models.IntegerField()
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.prefix_field_name = kwargs.pop("prefix_field_name")
        self.datetime_field = 'datetime'
        self.offset_seconds_field = 'offset_seconds'

        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Set this, so we receive all model fields in to_representation.
        self.source = '*'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """This function is called when an object instance is serialized. For example an instance retrieved from db.
        For example this serialization will lead into this function:
            >> instance = MyModel.objects.last()
            >> MyModelSerializer(instance).data
        """
        return get_isoformat_string_from_datetime(
            getattr(instance, self.datetime_field), getattr(instance, self.offset_seconds_field)
        )

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """This functions is called when a json object is serialized. For example on an Api call.
        The data returned from this function will be used to update the 'validated_data' dictionary.
        For example:
            >> data_to_be_serialized = {'datetime': '2021-04-10T07:51:15.958266-01:00', 'other_field': 10}
            >> MyModelSerializer(data=data_to_be_serialized)
        """
        if not isinstance(data, str):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect type. Expected a string")
        if not is_in_isoformat(data):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Data should be in isoformat")
        datetime = get_datetime_from_string(data)
        # This fields are going to be used to update validated_data dict.
        ret = {
            self.datetime_field: datetime,
            self.offset_seconds_field: get_utc_offset_seconds(datetime),
        }
        return ret
```

Usage:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    offset_seconds = models.IntegerField()

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datetime = CustomDateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('datetime', )
```